# I am trying to read a Json file in google colab, but I am getting an error

Tags: python, json, google-colaboratory

The google colab code is shown below:

```py
annotations = []
with open('/content/orig.json') as f:
  for line in f:
    annotations.append(json.loads(line))
```

The error which I get is

`JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 1 (char 2)`

Let me know if I need anymore details.

Comment: The error suggests that your json file was not properly formatted.

Comment: I have checked with json format and its in valid format.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your file is .json extension but every line is a JSON string, then line 2 in your JSON file 'orig.json' is malformed, it's not in correct JSON syntax, eg. JSON needs doublequotes around keys (properties) and values, not singlequotes.

But normally, when your files come with .json extension, you don't read line by line that way, parse the whole file instead:

```py
annotations = []

with open('/content/orig.json') as f:
    text = f.read()
    annotations.append(json.loads(text))
```

Comment: I understand what you want to say, but in this way when i run the command len(annotations) it results in 1 and when I want to check the value at index 0 using annotations[0] it gives whole json. However, what I want is only the value at first index, example below:
{'annotations': [{'area': 202208.0,
   'bbox': [112, 93, 568, 356],
   'category_id': 1,
   'id': 1,
   'ignore': 0,
   'image_id': 1,
   'iscrowd': 0,
   'segmentation': [[112, 93, 112, 449, 680, 449, 680, 93]]},
annotations[2] should return below:-
{'area': 69993.0,
   'bbox': [43, 174, 707, 99],
   ........}